# Проблема при переходе на https nginx

Tags: nginx, http, https

На сервере создано 2 конфига. Первый конфиг

```
map $http_user_agent $limit_bots {
        default 0;
        # ~*(google|yandex|GoogleBot|YandexBot) 1;
        #~*(bing|msnbot) 0;
        #~*(AltaVista|Slurp|BlackWidow|ChinaClaw|Custo|DISCo|Download|Demon|eCatch|EirGrabber|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|SuperHTTP|Surfbot|WebWhacker) 0;
        #~*(Express|WebPictures|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE|FlashGet|GetRight|GetWeb!|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It|GrabNet|Grafula|HMView|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It) 0;
        #~*(rafula|HMView|HTTrack|Stripper|Sucker|Indy|InterGET|Ninja|JetCar|Spider|larbin|LeechFTP|Downloader|tool|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|tAkeOut|WWWOFFLE) 0;
        #~*(GrabNet|NetSpider|Vampire|NetZIP|Octopus|Offline|PageGrabber|Foto|pavuk|pcBrowser|RealDownload|ReGet|SiteSnagger|SmartDownload|SuperBot|WebSpider) 0;
        #~*(Teleport|VoidEYE|Collector|WebAuto|WebCopier|WebFetch|WebGo|WebLeacher|WebReaper|WebSauger|eXtractor|Quester|WebStripper|WebZIP|Wget|Widow|Zeus) 0;
        #~*(Twengabot|htmlparser|libwww|Python|perl|urllib|scan|Curl|email|PycURL|Pyth|PyQ|WebCollector|WebCopy|webcraw) 0;
}


server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  xxxx.com;
        return 301 https://xxxx.com$request_uri;
        if ($host !~* ^(xxxx.com|www.xxxx.com)$ ) {
                return 444;
        }



if ( $remote_addr = 127.0.0.1 ) {
                set $limit_bots 0;
                }

if ( $remote_addr = 91.194.250.254 ) {
                set $limit_bots 0;
                }

#if ($http_user_agent ~* (AhrefsBot|YandexBot) ) {
if ($http_user_agent ~* (AhrefsBot) ) {
                set $limit_bots 1;
                }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-access.log main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/xxx-error.log;

        root       /var/www;
        index      index.php get_files_v3.php;

        location / {
            if ($limit_bots = 1) {
                return 403;
            }

                    # don�^�^�t check $uri/, send to php for nice error message
                    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /index.php {
            if ($limit_bots = 1) {
                return 403;
            }
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }


        location = /get_files_v3.php {
            if ($limit_bots = 1) {
                return 403;
            }
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css)$ {
                expires max;
        }

        location =/status_fmp {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                allow 193.239.152.34;
                allow 193.239.152.42;
                allow 193.239.152.45;
                allow 91.194.251.168;
                allow 91.194.251.57;
                deny all;
                expires -1;
        }



        location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|woff|woff2)$ {
                        expires max;
                access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-static-access.log;
                        }
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }
        client_max_body_size 2280m;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 9000;



location /nginx-status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow 193.239.152.34;
        allow 193.239.152.42;
        allow 193.239.152.45;
        allow 91.194.251.168;
        allow 91.194.251.57;
        deny all;
        expires -1;
            }
}
```

Вот второй, для htps

```
map $http_user_agent $limit_bots {
        default 0;
        # ~*(google|yandex|GoogleBot|YandexBot) 1;
        ~*(bing|msnbot) 0;
        ~*(AltaVista|Slurp|BlackWidow|ChinaClaw|Custo|DISCo|Download|Demon|eCatch|EirGrabber|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|SuperHTTP|Surfbot|WebWhacker) 0;
        ~*(Express|WebPictures|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE|FlashGet|GetRight|GetWeb!|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It|GrabNet|Grafula|HMView|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It) 0;
        ~*(rafula|HMView|HTTrack|Stripper|Sucker|Indy|InterGET|Ninja|JetCar|Spider|larbin|LeechFTP|Downloader|tool|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|tAkeOut|WWWOFFLE) 0;
        ~*(GrabNet|NetSpider|Vampire|NetZIP|Octopus|Offline|PageGrabber|Foto|pavuk|pcBrowser|RealDownload|ReGet|SiteSnagger|SmartDownload|SuperBot|WebSpider) 0;
        ~*(Teleport|VoidEYE|Collector|WebAuto|WebCopier|WebFetch|WebGo|WebLeacher|WebReaper|WebSauger|eXtractor|Quester|WebStripper|WebZIP|Wget|Widow|Zeus) 0;
        ~*(Twengabot|htmlparser|libwww|Python|perl|urllib|scan|Curl|email|PycURL|Pyth|PyQ|WebCollector|WebCopy|webcraw) 0;
}


server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/xxxx_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/xxxx_com.key;
        server_name  xxxx.com;
        if ($host !~* ^(xxxx.com|www.xxxx.com)$ ) {
                return 444;
        }



if ( $remote_addr = 127.0.0.1 ) {
                set $limit_bots 0;
                }

if ( $remote_addr = 91.194.250.254 ) {
                set $limit_bots 0;
                }

#if ($http_user_agent ~* (AhrefsBot|YandexBot) ) {
if ($http_user_agent ~* (AhrefsBot) ) {
                set $limit_bots 1;
                }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-access.log main;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/xxx-error.log;

        root       /var/www;
        index      index.php get_files_v3.php;

        location / {
            if ($limit_bots = 1) {
                return 403;
            }

                    # don�^�^�t check $uri/, send to php for nice error message
                    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /index.php {
            if ($limit_bots = 1) {
                return 403;
            }
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }


        location = /get_files_v3.php {
            if ($limit_bots = 1) {
                return 403;
            }
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }


        location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css)$ {
                expires max;
        }

        location =/status_fmp {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                allow 193.239.152.34;
                allow 193.239.152.42;
                allow 193.239.152.45;
                allow 91.194.251.168;
                allow 91.194.251.57;
                deny all;
                expires -1;
        }



        location ~* \.(css|js|png|gif|jpg|woff|woff2)$ {
                        expires max;
                access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-static-access.log;
                        }
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;
        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }
        client_max_body_size 228m;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;



location /nginx-status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow 193.239.152.34;
        allow 193.239.152.42;
        allow 193.239.152.45;
        allow 91.194.251.168;
        allow 91.194.251.57;
        deny all;
        expires -1;
            }
}
```

Используемый фреймворк - Kohana. При включении редиректа - сайт работает 2-3 минуты и нужно сделать php5-fpm restart . Сайт возобновляет работу так же - на 2-3 минуты. Потом снова 404 ошибка до перезагрузки. Помогите ,пожалуйста. Уже кучу статтей перечитал - ничего не помогает. В логах ngnix

> 2016/10/16 23:37:50 [crit] 25142#0: *2 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
>   while connecting to upstream, client: xx.249.76.79, server: xxx.com,
>   request: "GET /catalog/bmw/3/330-i-5560$
>   2016/10/16 23:37:50 [error] 25142#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory), client: xx.249.76.79, server: xxx.com, request:
>   "GET /catalog/bmw/3/330-i-55607/pylnik-rulevoj-rejki-716 HTT$

В логах php5-fpm
NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful

---

Спасибо. Оказалось, что просто сервер не выдерживал и ложился.

Comment: Ну, а в журналах, в журналах-то что? Какие ошибки?

Comment: Судя по ошибкам в логе `nginx` проблема на стороне `php-fpm`, смотри что у него в логах. И возможно есть смысл удалить всё лишее из конфига `nginx`, там явно понакручено лишнего (особенно в конфиге для http). Например зачем if с `return 444`? Запросы на левые домены так и так не попадут в этот `server` если не задать его как `default_server`